# Does a reincarnated Draconic Bloodline Sorcerer save his class abilities?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, reincarnation

It looks like that Draconic Bloodline Sorcerer got all his class abilities just from his dragon ancestor.

But does such ancestor provide sorcerer only with a Draconic Bloodline body, like ancestors usually does?

Or maybe sorcerer's soul and spirit are Draconic Bloodline, but his body isn't?

What would happen with Draconic Bloodline Sorcerer's abilities after using the *Reincarnation* spell onto such sorcerer's dead body?

Comment: The phrasing is a bit confusing. Is your question "What class abilities does a draconic bloodline sorcerer retain after being subjected to the reinarnate spell?"

Comment: @Szega Thank you! I rephrased it now.

Comment: "like ancestors usually does" — why would that be the case? I see no indication either way in the rules or lore.

Comment: It is not about rules or lore, just a common sense

Answer (score 14):

Mechanically, *Reincarnate* can only change the character's *race*, not their (sub)class.

> The magic fashions a new body for the creature to inhabit, which likely causes the creature's race to change...
>
> The reincarnated creature recalls its former life and experiences. **It retains the capabilities it had in its original form, except it exchanges its original race for the new one and changes its racial traits accordingly.**

So a draconic bloodline sorcerer would still be a draconic bloodline sorcerer after being *Reincarnated*.

Comment: Yes, draconic bloodlines are magical, not genetic.

Comment: +1, but honestly I wouldn't have a problem with a player who would ask for a roll to determine his new bloodline. It's not like it would be overpowered or anything.